# How to get in beach with sun my body with mobile

Tags: photo-editing, filters

I am new here and I would like to know how to get a photo of me "show my body only". I want to make it more specific what I mean. First I am not professional and It is just for social medias.I would like to know, which filters will be suitable , which position to "sun" (sun on left,right,back,front where should I have it).Secondly , what ever you would do in your own picture just to be looking good,not professional because I am not.Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every person is different!

Many of us like the same things; but, we all try to be an individual. We look a bit different, too. We like variety. Some things that you like may not appeal to me.

Because of all these things, there is no one-solution to your question. You must experiment. A professional has to experiment to find your *best* angle too.

**Professional photographers take many pictures during a photo session.** Then, they remove the bad ones—the ones that are not technically okay. They now have many "good" photos.

You are given these to choose the ones that you like the best.

**You must do the same thing.** Photograph yourself many times with each picture slightly different. Take a picture with the sun on one side. Then, turn a little and take another picture. Then, turn a little more and take another one. Do this again, and again until you have the sun on the other side.

Look at these and choose the one where you look the best. Now, you know where the sun should be for your best results.

Now, experiment with different expressions. Smile. Don't smile. Choose the expression where you look the best.

After you get the expression right, experiment with different head positions.
Look up. Look straight. Look down. Look left. Look right. Choose the best one.

When you find out what looks good for you, put all these things together and you will get a good photo of yourself. When you do it, take a few pictures at the same time and keep the best one. Be selective.